# Cannot clone the function parameter inside an isolated function

Tags: ballerina

I have the following isolated function which adds Record values to a array(defined as module level variable & isolated too)

```ballerina
isolated function add(Record r) {
    lock {
        arr.push(r)
    }
}
```

Here I'm not able to clone the "r" record. What is the reason for this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

You might not be able to clone because the type is not a subtype of `value:Cloneable`. You can explicitly create a new value by copying in relevant fields - e.g., `{a: r.intV, b: r.arrV.clone(), c: isolatedObj}`. Please refer to https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-spec/issues/856 (also see example with spread there), https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-spec/issues/1244

If it is a complicated structure of cloneable vs non-cloneable values, one approach to consider would be to see if the record can be split accordingly to define separate structures.

Please refer to the following link to learn more about clonables -

https://lib.ballerina.io/ballerina/lang.value/latest